# How long does it take ( and how hard ) to replace front strut and spring assembly on a 2008 CRV?

Tags: honda, crv, struts, springs

Just went to get my car inspected, mechanic told me that I need new front struts, car has 120k on it so it kinda makes sense. He quoted me $950, I called the auto- parts store and they told me that it would cost $180 per strut for complete struts. From what I can see, swapping them out is not that big a deal, I'm pretty handy, used to work on my car allot. How long do you think it would take to swap out the front strut assembly in a 2008 CRV, I have the tools I need, I would most likely just be using a jack and doing it right on the street.

Comment: If you have tools and skills it should be about one hour per side. Buy strut assemblies which have the springs included.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have [jack stands](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/54202/4152)? If not, that's something you'd really need to have. If you are handy and have all the tools, getting it done should not be an issue. Do a [search on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=2008+honda+crv+strut+replacement) and you should be able to find something. Remember also, you need to figure in the cost of an alignment as well. Time to do it really depends on your skills and stupid things like rusted bolts or ball joints which refuse to separate. If you feel you can get the job done in 4 hours, make sure you double it to be in the ballpark, but then figure it's going to take you longer even still. It's just the nature of working on cars.

Answer (score 0):

How long and how hard depends on your ability. We don't know that.

If you are a novice, it may not be a job you want. If you have moderate experience, it could take a few hours to all day, depending how rusted the bolts are and what tools you have. I have a lot of experience and have had these jobs take far longer than they should because of the age of the vehicle.

The most important things are the car be supported properly. And you have the proper tools to compress the springs, if you are not purchasing complete (quick) struts.

Things to consider when comparing DIY (Do It Yourself) to a professional shop.

- You aren't a certified professional, you are working in the street
- You don't have overhead costs (insurance, employees, building, equipment, etc.)
- The parts you get at the local store may not be the same quality the shop uses
- The cost probably includes all the minor pieces most DIYers forget (strut bearings, bumpers, covers, new hardware, etc.)
- The cost might include alignment (many people forget when finished)
- They warranty their work

Cost isn't always simply about money. If you are capable, good luck and be safe. When you are not sure and don't have the right equipment, it is better to be safe and pay to have it done.